# Python list function or list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anybody please explain to me the difference between these two ways of creating a list. Are they the same thing ? If not which one should I use ?

```
squares1 = [x**2 for x in range(1, 11)]
squares2 = list(x**2 for x in range(1, 11))
```

Comment: Both do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Why does it matter? There are subtle differences that do not matter 99% of the time. Generally I prefer `list(map(math.pow, range(1, 11), repeat(2)))` but its mainly a matter of taste.

Comment: They are identical. Prefer the first alternative.

Comment: Contrary to what is said in other comments they are **not** identical (`list` is faster, because list comprehensions can change result size, so `list` can pre-allocate exactly required memory). But again, most of the time **it doesn't matter**.

Comment: I think the first is a list-comprehension and the second one is part of the lambda stuff python offers. I believe most people like list-comprehension more then lambda but I cant offer any technical details here.

Comment: List comprehensions do not pre-allocated exactly the required memory. They essentially work like a for-loop with append, which overallocates

Comment: @TheFoom the second o e has nothing to do with `lambda`, it is a generator expression that gets materialized into a list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh thank you :) Once again I learned a bit more. So I quess like in the real answer below, the main difference then is lazy vs eager?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a slight bit of difference in their performance as can be seen from the following:

```
squares1 = [x**2 for x in range(1, 11)]
```

> 3.07 µs ± 70 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
squares2 = list(x**2 for x in range(1, 11))
```

> 3.65 µs ± 35.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

this can primarily be because in case 1 you are iterating and generating values for the list at the same time.

In case 2 you are generating values while iterating and then at the end of it converting the same to a list and this is then stored as a given variable.

Answer (score 3):

I way I see it, first program directly initializes squares1 as a list through list comprehension.

The other one first creates a generator class object and then converts it into a list. I think first approach is more efficient.

There are little differences between lists and generators but as per my knowledge and experience lists do the job faster and generators do it lazily yielding single result for every iteration. For most of your tasks, I'd recommend opting for lists.

Answer (score 2):

The first method is quicker. This is because when they get compiled into bytecode, the first one becomes

```
0  LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7fc95aea9ed0, file "<dis>", line 1>)
2  LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
4  MAKE_FUNCTION            0
6  LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
8  LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
10 LOAD_CONST               3 (11)
12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
14 GET_ITER
16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
18 RETURN_VALUE
```

and the second becomes

```
0  LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
2  LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x7fc95aea9ed0, file "<dis>", line 1>)
4  LOAD_CONST               1 ('<genexpr>')
6  MAKE_FUNCTION            0
8  LOAD_NAME                1 (range)
10 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
12 LOAD_CONST               3 (11)
14 CALL_FUNCTION            2
16 GET_ITER
18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
20 CALL_FUNCTION            1
22 RETURN_VALUE
```

This means the second method takes two more instructions, slowing it down, even if it is just a tiny bit.

On my laptop, a million iterations of the first take 4.651s, and a million iterations of the second method takes 5.483s.

Comment: Those two instructions aren't what's slowing it down, though. They only occur once, not per iteration. The reason for the slowdown is that iterating I over a generator is slow in general, and you have two calls to `next` per item that end up in your list

Answer (score 2):

In first case you use list comprehension syntax. It's the fastest way to map some function on list in python.

In second case you create a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

```
(x**2 for x in range(1000))
```

and send it to the list() function immediately. There is almost no difference in your case, because you get the same list and almost the same execution time:

```
%%timeit
[i**2 for i in range(1000)]

Out:
170 µs ± 774 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%%timeit
list(i**2 for i in range(1000))

Out:
187 µs ± 2.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

But I'm not sure about memory usage in both cases - looks like they are the same.