# How do you create a random list of integers, but exclude a certain number?

Tags: python, random

I'd like to create a random list of numbers in python, but exclude a certain number, k.

I can create a random list of integers:
 `l = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(5)]`
Then I can remove the number, k, if it's there, and add another random number in the range, but this seems like too many steps.

In researching this, It's quite easy to find out how to create a random number from a range and exclude a certain number, for example:
`print (choice([i for i in range(0,9) if i not in [2,5,7]]))`
I could do this the amount of times I need to create the array -- but this seems more complex than necessary.

Would appreciate some feedback this

Comment: If you want a practical solution that theoretically doesn't always work: Generate _n_ times the amount of random numbers you actually need, and then filter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a list of the numbers in the range, and remove `k` from the list. Then you can use `random.choices()` to select multiple elements from the list.

```
numbers = list(range(0, 11))
numbers.remove(k)
result = random.choices(numbers, k=5)
```

Comment: Works, but depending on the range and amount of numbers you need this seems a bit wasteful (e.g. `range(0, 1000000)`)

Comment: Memory is cheap. But feel free to post a better solution.

Comment: I'm not saying my solution would be better, for the range from 0 to 10 this is a great solution, perhaps also for 0 to 1000. It's just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a generator that yields random numbers of your choosing, and take the first n:

```
def random_numbers_except(a, b, exclusions):
    while True:
        while (choice := random.randint(a, b)) in exclusions:
            pass
        yield choice

numbers = [number for _, number in zip(range(5), random_numbers_except(0, 10, [2, 5, 7]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also create your generator and use that in your list comprehension.

```py
def my_random_generator(n_values, min_value, max_value, excluded_values=None):
    if excluded_values is None:
        excluded_values = []

    count = 0

    while count < n_values:
        value = random.randint(min_value, max_value)
        while value in excluded_values:
            value = random.randint(min_value, max_value)
        yield value
        count += 1


# Then
l = [_ for _ in my_random_generator(5, 0, 10, [2, 5, 7])]

# Or, (added after the discussion below)
l = list(my_random_generator(5, 0, 10, [2, 5, 7]))
```

Comment: Which could of course use the assignment operator to be shorter, in Python>=3.8

Comment: Why do you use an awkward list comprehension at the finish instead of `l = list(my_random_generator(5, 0, 10, [2, 5, 7]))`?

Comment: Force of habits, I guess. At least it's not awkward to me anymore. Now theoretically, I'm not sure yet if the question and answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51861670/9981846 apply here, but I'd say so.

Comment: That's an interesting link, particularly for the fact that different answers reach opposite conclusions for the two options.  The difference isn't large enough to matter except in the most critical application, therefore I'd go for readability and I think my alternative is more readable.  You may continue to disagree of course.

Comment: I thank you for the question, and discussion. I do agree that `list` is more straightforward and could of course be used here instead. I like the learning opportunity my answer provides, though, and that's why I'm sticking to it for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the random numbers to the range you need and subtract the amount of numbers you want to exclude. Whenever an exceptional number is chosen, you can map it to the end of the range.

Does that make sense? If not, maybe the code does:

```
import random

random_range = range(0,1000)
exclude = [5, 55, 555]

def generate(n:int, ran: range, exclude:list):
    exclusive_range = range(ran.start, ran.stop-len(exclude))
    randoms = []
    for i in range(n):
        r = random.choice(exclusive_range)
        if r in exclude:
            r = exclusive_range.stop + exclude.index(r)
        randoms.append(r)
    return randoms

x = generate(1000, random_range, exclude)
```

In my example, 5 will be mapped to 997, 55 will be panned to 998 and 555 will be mapped to 999.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose random numbers from a range that is one shorter, and then for each individual selection add 1 to it when it is greater or equal to *k*:

```
import random

k = 50  # number to exclude
n = 100  # range: choices should be in {0,...,49,51,...,99}
rnd = random.randrange(0, n - 1)  # in {0,...,98}
rnd += int(rnd >= k)
```